# Is $H_n(X) \cong$ $Hom(H_n(X);Z)$ ?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering if the following is true.
Is 
$H_n(X) \cong$ $Hom(H_n(X);Z)$ ? Where $H_n(X)$ denote the nth homology group of a topological space X

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $H^n(X)$ on the left? An finitely generated abelian group $A$ has $A = \operatorname{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Z})$ iff $A$ is torsion-free.

Answer (score 3):

No. The RHS is torsion-free, but the LHS might have torsion. The simplest exmaple is $H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

The correct statement relates homology and cohomology; look up the universal coefficient theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's depend of the coefficients. If it is integral the homology can be a finite group $Z/n$ like the projective space.